# Mixed Content Error : This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS in MERN project on AWS

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, mern

My project is deployed on AWS ec2 instance. After adding SSL to my domain I am start getting this error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/' was loaded over
> HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource
> 'http://14.1.41.10/api/product/productsforcarousel'. This request has
> been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

This is a MERN project and problem is arrive after putting SSL. Here is my code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

mongoose
  .connect(`mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_URL}`, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(5000);   
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

And here is nginx code

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    root /var/www/Example_Pro/public;
    index index.php index.js index.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl/ssl.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/nginx/ssl/private.key";

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256";

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8043;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    proxy_read_timeout  90;
    proxy_buffering     off;
    proxy_redirect      http://127.0.0.1:8043  https://example.com;
    }
}
```